# Makumba - how to set null to pointer value with API

Tags: api, makumba

I'm wondering what would be the best way to set a NULL (or NIL) value to a pointer in makumba using the API?

I've tried something like this:

```
Dictionary<String,Object> emptyActivity = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
emptyActivity.put("activity", null);
db.update((Pointer)pointer, emptyActivity);
```

However I can't put null to the dictionary so I'm not sure what to do here. Is there a java object representing a null value?

Comment: OK, managed to find the solution. `Pointer.Null` represents the null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of null, you should use an instance of Makumba's NullObject (http://www.makumba.org/api/org/makumba/NullObject.html).

For pointers, you can reuse the constant Pointer.Null (http://www.makumba.org/api/org/makumba/Pointer.html#Null)

So, your code is then

```
emptyActivity.put("activity", Pointer.Null);
```